# Aplicações Genexus + IIS 64 Bits

Tags: c#, iis, genexus, 64-bits

Bom dia, boa tarde, boa noite amigos.

Estou utilizando GeneXus para gerar uma aplicação e tenho algumas dlls grandes, cujas rotinas demoram pra abrir a primeira vez e na segunda já vão mais rápido.

Tenho o seguinte cenário:
-A DLL tem 2 MB, portanto é uma tela com bastante campos
-Em 32 Bits a tela demora 2 segundos para carregar
-Em 64 Bits a tela demora 17 segundos para carregar a primeira vez
-O chaveamento entre um modo e outro faço através da propriedade "Habilitar aplicativos de 32 bits" no pool da minha aplicação no IIS.

Configurações do GeneXus
-GeneXus X Evolution 2 Upgrade 7 - Build 109528
-Gerador C# para SQL Server
-Sistema operacional: Windows 7 64 Bits

Agradeço demais toda e qualquer ajuda fornecida :)

Answer (score 0):

Prezado colega:

Na documentação:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8949,Config+HttpHandlers+Section+Model+Property,

Experimente usar a opção: HttpHandlerFactory

Mas atenção, somente em ambiente de desenvolvimento. Acredito que isso possa resolver o problema da demora na prototipação.

Att,
Bruno

Comment: Prezado colega,
Atualmente minha KB já está configurada com esse valid na propriedade "Config HttpHandlers"... =(